# Help links in Kohana not working

Tags: routes, http-status-code-404, kohana-3

So I am pretty new to Kohana, and what I have to do right now is make some changes for a client's website. The client's site is written using Kohana and I have the files and everything needed on my local system. I made the required bootstrap.php and .htaccess changes. Now when I load the site, the homepage shows up fine, but when I click on the links, they do not work.

So for example, `http://localhost/kohana_site/` shows me the homepage

I click on about, the url shows: `http://localhost/kohana_site/about`, and I get a 404.

Now I experimented, and I tried `http://localhost/index.php/about` and that works!

So I am a little stumped and I dont want to change the routing of the like 50+ links on my client's site. How might I resolve this?

Comment: Are they using an add-on domain?

Answer (score 0):

Does your new bootstrap file contain 'index_file' => false  while invoking the Kohana::init function?

`Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => 'your_site_url',
    'index_file'=> FALSE
));`